# Redefenition of typedef enum

Tags: c++, types, enums, typedef

For example, we have following source files:

types.h:

```
#pragma once

typedef enum { RED, GREEN, BLUE } myColorSet;
```

whatever.h:

```
#pragma once

myColorSet getColor( int args[] );
```

whatever.cpp

```
#include "whatever.h"
#include "types.h"

myColorSet getColor( int args[] ) {

    //returning the color according to args
}
```

Compiling this throws:

> 'myColorset' : redefinition; symbol cannot be overloaded with a typedef.
>   See declaration of 'myColorset'.

It's a little bit confusing for me, but it seems like compilator thinks that

```
myColorSet getColor( ... );
```

from whatever.h is a declaration of a `myColorSet`. I want to use `myColorSet` as a return type in `getColor` function. Am I missing something?

Also, when I include "types.h" in whatever.h (instead of whatever.cpp) it works fine. But as far as I know it's better to avoid including in .h files.

Should I just put include in whatever.h or there is another (right?) way? Thank you.

Comment: you're not including `types.h` in `whatever.h` because... ? Don't make header files chain-dependant based on the .cpp file they're included in. It is a dreadful habit. The consumer of `whatever.h` expects it will bring what it needs to the translation unit. Whoever told you " its better to avoid including  in .h files" should be put on you "do not listen to them" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare `myColorSet getColor( int args[] )`, the compiler does not yet know `myColorSet`; but it needs to, because `myColorSet` is the return type of that function.

You are right, it's better to avoid including in .h files. But this applies only to the situation when you have to choose between an `#include` and a forward declaration. In that case, a forward declaration is preferred. There are cases where a forward declartion is not sufficient. In these cases you *have* to use `#include`.

You can get away without changing the headers by means of a `whatever.cpp` like

```
#include "types.h"
// myColorSet is now known, so we can declare getColor(int args[]) now:
#include "whatever.h"

myColorSet getColor( int args[] ) {

    //returning the color according to args
}
```

but this is not recommended, because now compilation depends on the order in which headers are included.

Comment: Very good explanation as well as your advice about includes order which luckily explains why I was almost sure that if I include something in whatever.cpp the compiler would know about it consuming whatever.h x) Thank you, kind sir.

Answer (score 2):

In whatever.h, you need to put

```
#include "types.h"
```

Or without, the compiler will not recognize the type, even if it has been declared in whatever.cpp with whatever.h; the error is occuring in whatever.h

Another solution would be to get rid of types.h, and put that `typedef` in whatever.h, and remove the `#include "types.h"` from whatever.cpp, which would mean you would have to do `#include "types.h"` in whatever, and would mean you would have less files to include [easier to remember]